# Is there a graphical proof that $9n+1$ is triangular if $n$ is?

Tags: visualization, proof-without-words, triangular-numbers

It is [straightforward to prove](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/If_n_is_Triangular_then_so_is_9n_%2B_1) that if $n$ is a triangular number then $9n+1$ must be.

Is there a systematic decomposition of a triangle made of $9n+1$ dots into nine triangles of $n$ dots plus one left over to illustrate this fact visually?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Visual proof. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

[image]

Of course it doesn't depend on the base triangle, here is the same with $T_4$:

[image]

With regard to the pattern mentionned by Teresa Lisbon in a comment above, here is how $25T_n+3$ shows up:

[image]

The pattern may be repeated with a number of *"holes"* that is itself a triangle number, for instance:

[image]

In light red, the repeated pattern.

This pattern yields the general result: $8T_pT_q+T_p+T_q=T_n$ with $n=2pq+p+q$, and of course $T_n=\frac12n(n+1)$. It's not difficult to prove algebraically.

Comment: What software did you use to create this graphic?

Comment: @user2661923 Excel.

Answer (score 7):

Another one, based on the fact that centered hexagonal numbers can be expressed as $6T_n+1$:
[image]

Comment: This is beautiful! :))

Comment: +1, try it for : $n$ triangular implies $25n+3$ triangular! The patterns are rewarding